# Get Json field value from Json

Tags: sql-server

I want to get "OrderNumber" field value from below mentioned json string. Pleas suggest best way to get the same

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)=

  '{"ErpOrderResponses":[{"OrderSubmitStatus":"Ok","TransactionId":"{5EAB3ADC-EB9B-47F7-98B8-1449E2CC0A6B}","OrderNumber":7000027934,"CustomerNumber":80038707,"Description":"Request Successful","ResponseCode":"Success","ResponseType":"None","Errors":[]}],"IsErpUnavailable":false,"IsSuccessful":true,"IsPartiallySuccessful":false,"IsValidationFailed":false,"IsFailed":false}'

    DECLARE @OrderNumber BIGINT = 
    (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@JSON,CHARINDEX('OrderNumber',@JSON)+1,
                                                        CHARINDEX(',',@JSON,
                                                                        CHARINDEX('OrderNumber',@JSON)+1
                                                                )-CHARINDEX('OrderNumber',@JSON)
                                                        )
                                                        ,'RDERNUMBER":',''),',','') )
    --SELECT CAST( @OrderNumber AS BIGINT)

    SELECT  @OrderNumber
```

Comment: What version of Sql Server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are on SQL Server 2016 or greater, you can use the JSON_VALUE function to parse out an individual value:

```
SELECT  JSON_VALUE(@JSON,'$.ErpOrderResponses[0].OrderNumber');
```

If you are going to be processing more than one row, I recommend you use OPENJSON for better performance:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@JSON,'$.ErpOrderResponses')  
    WITH (OrderSubmitStatus varchar(20),OrderNumber bigint);
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017